# Updating User entity with unique fields in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have simple class User, with unique `username` and `password` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "pass_word", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String password;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
}
```

and class `Contact`, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "contact_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "displayName", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String displayName;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String email

    @ManyToOne()
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to properly update User. 
For example:

I have initial two Users with 
User1:
username=a and password=a

User2:
username=b and password=b.

Now if I change User1's username to 'ao', that goes thorough and database gets updated. But after, that if I try to change User1's username back to original username, that is to 'a' and password remains the same ('b'), I get `SQLException`.

Here is code:

```
@Override
public User updateUser(User user) {

    if(!userRepository.existsById(user.getId())){
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("UserId: " + user.getId() + " not found");
    }


    Optional<User> u1 = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if (u1.isPresent()){
        if (u1.get().getId() != user.getId()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    Optional<User> u2 = userRepository.findByPassword(user.getPassword());
    if (u2.isPresent()){
        if(u2.get().getId() != user.getId()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    return userRepository.findById(user.getId()). map(u -> {
            u.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
            u.setLastName(user.getLastName());
            u.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            u.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            return userRepository.save(u);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("UserId: " + user.getId() + " not found"));
}
```

I have to mention that `User` that is being passed to `upadateUser(User user)` has it `Set<Contacts>` but each of those `Contacts` doesn't have a `User`. Also, User being passed also have the id of the User being edited(updated) on the frontend.

I'm new to Hibernate and Spring in general.

Comment: Your whole update method doesn't make sense? ALso why on earth would a password need to be unique?

Comment: Hi, actually the two Ifs were there just for some debugging purposes. Password must be unique by an assignment. I know it's stupid. Last part should be okey, I guess standard way how to set new values and save the user. Can you figure where I am making mistake?

Comment: You are changing the password and that has to be unique so you cannot save. What is in your `return` statement is all you need, nothing more, nothing less.